# How can I do tag-entry field (as done by Stack Overflow). Javascript is ok

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

Please can anyone show me a proper way to program the Tags field so that it looks like the stackoverflow one. 
As in:

[image]

I suspect it is done in HTML/CSS and Javascript. Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated. I would be grateful as well, if you can write some illustration code or direct me to some sort of tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried "View Source" and "Inspect element" in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Yes I did that before asking this question. Thanks anyway

Comment: So how far did you get with that and what still needs clarifying?

Comment: There are a lot of plugins (most for jQuery) that do this. A quick search for "facebook-like tagging" should somewhat give similar results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use jQuery here are some good options:

From the jQuery folks themselves:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryTagEditor

This one is easiest to see in action right from the web page link:
http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/

Others:

https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input
https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it
http://ioncache.github.com/Tag-Handler/

Comment: Thanks for your help! Those were really helpful. I'm glad you took the time to direct me to some good plug-ins.

Comment: @CompilingCyborg - This one's also pretty good, actually: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/